# Line Clamp with Link at the end of the last line next to the ellipsis

Tags: html, css

**The ask to show the 'Read more' link at the end of the fourth line(image below).**

[image]

If I use the line-clamp it looks like below:

[image]

I tried using different approaches, but there is an issue that word does not break properly.

[image]

Below is the code:

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.read-more {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
}

.read-more::before {
  content: '...';
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing.
    This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing. This is for testing.
    This is the issue with this approach</div>
  <div class="read-more">
    <a href="">Read More ></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you could you help in solving the issue, that would be really helpful. And whether this is achievable or not using CSS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not entirely clear what the question/problem is here - could you clarify the exact nature of the issue?

Comment: The expectation is to achieve what is in the 1st image. The best solution I came up with is in 3rd image. However, in 3rd image the area I have marked in red, 's' of word 'this' is partially visible.

Comment: I doubt there is any CSS solution that works better than what you already have with version #3. There is no existing mechanism to specifically achieve what you want, so you can only "fake" it by using such an approach with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found is using JS to cut and manipulate the truncated text...

```
$('.box-to-cut').each(function() {
    /*
        If text is truncated (with a line-clamp?)
    */
    if (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight) {
        let text = $(this).text();

        let link = $('<span class="more-text">Read More</span>');
        $(this).append(link);

        /*
            Cut a char at a time from text, until it fits (taking into account 
            also the size of the "read more" link)
        */
        while(this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight) {
            text = text.slice(0, -1);
            $(this).empty().text(text + '... ');
            $(this).append(link);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at solution #2 in [this article](https://dev.to/coderchamp/truncate-text-with-css-the-possible-ways-1p4o).

Snippet:

```css
/**Major Properties**/
overflow:hidden;
line-height: 2rem;
max-height: 8rem;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
display: block;
display: -webkit-box;
overflow: hidden !important;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-webkit-line-clamp: 4;
```

The article references a codepen by Shan Shah demonstrating the result: https://codepen.io/ShanShahOfficial/pen/wvBYwaB

You might want to leave out some properties according to your needs (like the `line-height`).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I have to show one 'Read more' link at end of 4th line after ellipsis.